# Django: how to save additional fields in a database?

Tags: database, django

I have a class in models.py:

```
class Person(AbstractUser):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

It`s related to AbstractUser from contrib/models.py

I`ve made a class that lets make additional fields to it.

```
class ExtraTextField(models.Model): 
    add = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    new_field_text = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name='content')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.new_field_text)

class AddText(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ExtraTextField
    extra = 0

class AdminForm(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    inlines = [AddText]
```

As you see, amount of fields is not defined, so I can`t just put them into class Person. But as a logical continuing, these additional fields are not saved in the database. Please, help, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you fix the indent of second piece of code ?

Comment: Sorry, didn`t notice.

Comment: Is migration the only way?